# Proxmox Container - Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: debian, proxmox, containers

For my company i need to manage a proxmox machine hosted on OVH.
The proxmox contains some container and i've added a new one, it's a debian 10 container.

I then set the network parameters, assigning a static IP, gateway and DNS server respecting the network parameters and consistently with the containers already present on the proxmox.

When i try to reach the external network, for example with a ping, i've the message `'Temporary failure in name resolution'`.

I've checked the /etc/resolv.conf file and followed the troubleshooting steps in this article [open fw linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/opening-a-port-on-linux), but I still can't reach outside the network.

I'm quite new to using containers in proxmox, do you have any suggestions or recommendations?
Thanks in advance

- /etc/resolve.conf

```
 --- BEGIN PVE ---
search localhost
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
# --- END PVE ---
```

Comment: Well, does your container have an access to the Internet? What `ping 8.8.8.8` shows? (It can't show failure in a name resolution, because we already gave it a literal IP address.)